# Error converting data type varchar to float while using ISNULL and NULLIF function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, isnull, type-conversion

When I am using following SQL code I get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

My code:

```
select 
    [DEVELOPIN], 
    avg([DEVELOPINGCOST]) as [AVG DEVELOPINGCOST],
    avg([SOFTWARECOST]) as [ AVG SOFTWARECOST],
    ISNULL(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST] / NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES], 0)), 'No Sale') as [AVG PER Sale] 
from
    [dbo].[SOFTWARE] 
group by 
    [DEVELOPIN]
```

The error has been isolated to this expression:

```
ISNULL(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST] / NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES], 0)), 'No Sale') as [AVG PER Sale]
```

Comment: 1. Complete some basic troubleshooting by selecting only _one_ field at a time and isolating the field causing the issue. 2. What are the datatypes of the fields causing your issue?

Comment: ISNULL(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST]/NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES],0)),'No Sale') as [AVG PER Sale]

Comment: I will edit your question. After I edit your question, please edit it and add the datatypes of these fields

Comment: following code is working fine :select [DEVELOPIN],avg([DEVELOPINGCOST])as [AVG DEVELOPINGCOST],avg([SOFTWARECOST]) as [ AVG SOFTWARECOST],
ISNULL(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST]/NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES],0)),'0') as [AVG PER Sale] from [dbo].[SOFTWARE] GROUP BY [DEVELOPIN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My the error is because the result of your first expression in ISNULL function is float and you are assigning value of type varchar i.e 'No Sale' when exp evaluates to null Also make sure that datatype of both expression of nullif function matches
Try converting your expression to varchar

```
select [DEVELOPIN]
      ,avg([DEVELOPINGCOST])as [AVG DEVELOPINGCOST]
      ,avg([SOFTWARECOST]) as [ AVG SOFTWARECOST]
      ,  ISNULL(CAST(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST]/NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES],0)) as varchar),'No Sale') 
 from[dbo].[SOFTWARE] GROUP BY [DEVELOPIN]
```

Comment: convert(varchar(20),ISNULL(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST]/NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES],0)),'NO Sale')) as [AVG PER Sale]------------still having same error

Comment: it should be like ISNULL(CAST(AVG([DEVELOPINGCOST]/NULLIF([SOLDCOPIES],0)) as varchar),'No Sale')

Try running  query in response